# Meaning of ここまでのことをやったんです

Tags: meaning

I am having some difficulties in trying to understand the below. Particularly the usage of し and the meaning of ここまでのことをやったんです as it is not clear from context who the agent is (i.e. is it the speaker or the listener who has done these things, as the have both done some terrible things) and the meaning of ここまでのこと is not quite clear.

To provide a bit more context, the speaker is trying to press the listener for why they have done what they did, as the listeners actions have caused the collapse of the organisation (that they are both a part of). This is after the listener provides a reason that the speaker thinks is made up.

> 何をごまかそうとしているんですか？
>
> 今更、何を言われても私は傷つきませんし、**ここまでのことをやったんです**。もし、私が傷ついたとしても、それがなんだと言うのですか？

I understand what the rest of it means:

- 今更、何を言われても私は傷つきません(at this point, I won't be hurt by whatever you say)
- もし、私が傷ついたとしても、それがなんだと言うのですか？ (Even if it does hurt me, what does it matter)

Comment: Without (much) more context **in the original language**, one could not be certain of who it is that has done ここまでのこと.

Answer (score 1):

"ここまでのこと" would be like, "an action of certain magnitude" lets say this person was being bullied and they did something very over the top to hurt this person, so "You've gone this far" or something would be it? I guess if it would be put into English it would probably come to the head and be like,

> You've/they've gone this far, words aren't going to do anything to me at this point